# add class to the element when clicked from ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I just want to add a tooltip to the element which is clicked.
Tooltip is added to all repeat elements when clicked. Please help me.

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in listOfMenu" class="repeat_container">

      <div ng-repeat="menu in item" class="repeat_block" ng-click="getTool(menu,menu.pricelist.length)" >
        <div class="shadow img_cont">
          <img src="{{menu.itemimage}}" class="item_img">

            <div ng-repeat="innerItem in menu.pricelist | limitTo:1">
                {{innerItem.itemprice}}
            </div>
         </div>
          <div>
              {{menu.menuitemname}}
          </div>
          <div ng-repeat="menu in addToCart" class="add_circle" ng-show="circle">
             {{menu.quantity}}
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the div in:

```
<div ng-repeat="menu in item" class="repeat_block" ng-click="getTool(menu,menu.pricelist.length)" ng-class="{'clicked': menu.clicked}">
```

In `getTool` method

```
menu.clicked = true;
```

but you should put `clicked:false` to all others `menu` in `items`